# Create Internet Explorer variable from shell.application object

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I'm retrieving an active internet explorer tab to run an automation script for an authenticated site. I need to get the application instance itself as something to operate on, as I have a way to navigate to the page I want since the button has no ID to call it by.

I start by finding the right page here, and then from there things are smooth.

```
Dim oShell, oWSHShell, sTitle, wndw, bMatch, oSelect
set oShell =createobject("shell.application")
set oWSHShell = createobject("wscript.shell")
sHTMLTitle = "Add Account"

bMatch =false 
for each wndw in oShell.windows 
    if instr(lcase(typename(wndw.document)), "htmldocument") > 0 then 
        sTitle =wndw.document.title
        if Instr(sTitle, sHTMLTitle)<> 0  then 
            bMatch =true 
            exit for 
        end if 
    end if 
next
```

Is there a way I can save the oShell object as something I can reference later on? Any reference I have seen for declaring an IE object is for making a brand new window which won't work here, as you would have to re-authenticate yourself and defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: I have done some testing with creating an IE object and navigating to the URL I need to go to, but while this keeps authentication/login, it creates a brand new instance of IE, which is not what Im looking for. Also, creating an object by

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

And then using

    ie = wndw

In the loop doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then I think you were on the right track, based on your comment. `wndw` is your IE object. But you need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning an object reference. For example:

```
Set objSaveIE = Nothing

for each wndw in oShell.windows 
    if instr(lcase(typename(wndw.document)), "htmldocument") > 0 then 
        sTitle =wndw.document.title
        if Instr(sTitle, sHTMLTitle)<> 0  then 
            Set objSaveIE = wndw 
            exit for 
        end if 
    end if 
next

' Now you can use objSaveIE as you would any other IE object...
If Not objSaveIE Is Nothing Then objSaveIE.Navigate "www.google.com"
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I guess using set is one of the quirks of moving from VB to VBS.